# Using inline JQuery when loading it in the footer

Tags: php, jquery

I am using WordPress and loading my JQuery just before the `</body>` tag as recommended.

I need to use some inline JQuery on one of the pages as I want to pass a PHP variable to the JQuery. But I get the:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Because JQuery has not been loaded yet.

Is there a method of getting around this?

I have thought of just loading JQuery in the head (don't really want to do this) or using AJAX to pass the variable (seems like too much if there's a simpler method).

Comment: You don't need jquery to "*pass a PHP variable to [javascript]*".  `<script>var myvar = '<? echo $myVar; ?>';</script>`.  You can also have a script tag *after* the jquery script tag which has your php->javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use WP functions for it:

```php
$script = <<<SCRIPT
$('#some_id').addClass('some-class');
SCRIPT;
wp_add_inline_script('my_inline_script', $script);
```